# How can I see the full text content of a Django `Request`?

Tags: django, http

I'm working in Django and I'm inspecting a `Request` object in my debug probe. How can I see the request's full textual contents, including all headers and everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual raw request no longer exists once Django has processed it. If you want to see it then you'll need to either use a packet sniffer to capture it before it has been processed, or some client-side tool such as Firebug in order to inspect it on the client.